# Can someone explain what backfeeding is and how I can protect my Pi from it?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, safety

So I read something about "backfeeding" and that it can damage my Pi. What exactly is it? I didn't understand the article. BTW, I'm a complete noob so please try to be as un-technical as possible.

I'm using a portable charger with a micro USB. It's 2.1 AMPS. I don't know how good the quality of it is, I just found it somewhere in my house.

Also, where in the pi do I plug it into?

I'm using a Pi 3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Forget the antediluvian references to backfeeding, it is irrelevant to modern Pi.

You need to plug a microUSB cable into the Pi3 power socket (next to the HDMI connector).